# Is it possible to let mysql update itself by changing other tables?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table1 containing variables called: v1, v2, v3, etc.

And I have another table2 containing variables called: y1, y2, y3, etc.

where y = f(v_s). v_s means some of the v1, v2, v3, etc.

When I update some value, let's say I added a new set of data of v_s into table1, is it possible for mysql to update y_s automatically?

Also I'm using python to maneuver my database. Just FYI.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, using a trigger http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/trigger-syntax.html or events scheduler http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html or a cron job.

Comment: Fred is right.  Also - FOREIGN KEYs do this as well. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84434/cascade-primary-key-update-to-all-referencing-foreign-keys and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Reference to mysql triggers - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Triggers http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: @MarkManning Not quite. Foreign key constraints don't *cause* updates to the parent table, they merely *require* them.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: The original posting did not state that they wanted the update to update the parent table but WHEN the parent table is updated can MySQL update other tables.  Therefore foreign keys are an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html). In your case the code would look something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_table2
  BEFORE INSERT ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO table2
        (y1, y2, y3)
      VALUES
        (f(NEW.v1), f(NEW.v2), f(NEW.v3));
```

The reference to `NEW.v1` refers to the value of `v1` in the newly-inserted row.